# Why does my loop carry on even though it meets the condition?

Tags: loops, delphi, while-loop

I'm creating a program and it supposed to be like this: There's an unknown amount of people coming to an event. The program should get the names and age of the people who register and if the age is below 13, then this should be counted as a kid and if the age is 13 or greater, they should be counted as an adult. The names will be displayed on a memo and the amount of kids and adults present should also be displayed (I displayed to an Edit box).

The problem I am having is that I used a while loop. For example my condition is, if the name in uppercase is 'EXIT' the program should terminate, but this isn't happening. Instead the program goes on to ask for age and then terminates.

Here is my code:

```
  name:= inputbox('dialog','Enter your name', '');
  edit1.Text:=name;
  adults:=0;
  children:=0;

  while uppercase(name) <> 'EXIT' do
  begin
    name:= inputbox('dialog','Enter your name', '');
    memo1.Lines.Add(''+name);
    age := strtoint(inputbox('age', 'Enter your age', ''));
    if age<13 then
    begin
      children:=children+1;
      edit3.Text:=inttostr(children)
    end
    else if age>=13 then
    begin
      adults:=adults+1;
      edit2.Text:=inttostr(adults);
    end ;
    showmessage('Hello '+name+', Welcome to our funday');
  end;  // while
```

Comment: Not a Delphi programmer but I guess that is the same as other languages, the while condition get tested only at the start of the cycle, not during the code block inside the cycle

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code?

Comment: You are experiencing this behavior because 'name' variable is set after you ask for 'Enter your name'.  So, the behavior is as designed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code continues to execute because that's exactly the way you wrote it. You need to test after the name is entered to see if you should continue and ask the age. (`name` is a poor variable name, as it's easily confused with `TForm.Name`, so I've changed it to `AName` in the code below.)

```
begin
  Adults := 0;
  Children := 0;

  while True do
  begin
    AName:= InputBox('dialog','Enter your name', '');
    if UpperCase(AName) = 'EXIT' then 
      Break;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(AName);
    Age := StrToInt(InputBox('Age', 'Enter your age', ''));
    if Age < 13 then
    begin
      Children := Children + 1;
      Edit3.Text := IntToStr(Children)
    end
    else if Age >= 13 then
    begin
      Adults := Adults + 1;
      Edit2.Text := IntToStr(Adults);
    end;
    ShowMessage('Hello ' + AName + ', Welcome to our funday');
  end;
end;
```

You may want to reconsider your user interface. Edit controls are designed for use when the user can change the content, and using them to display values the user can't edit isn't really appropriate. I'd suggest using *TLabel* instead; in fact, you could get by with just one using something like this:

```
Label1.Caption := Format('%d adults, %d children', [Adults, Children]);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I was new to looping structures and your guide has helped a lot. You were correct about the GUI, I did change my GUI. The program works properly now. I have also learned that I should use better variable names.

Answer (score 2):

You ask for the name, then you ask for the age unconditionally, so it should be no surprise that the loop doesn't exit in between the two. The check to exit the loop should happen after you ask for the name, but before you ask for the age.

```
adults   := 0;
children := 0;

while true do
begin
    name := inputbox('dialog', 'Enter your name (or "exit" to exit)', '');
    if uppercase(name) = 'EXIT' then
        break;

    memo1.Lines.Add(''+name);

    age := strtoint(inputbox('age', 'Enter your age', ''));
    if age < 13 then
        children := children + 1;
    else
        adults := adults + 1;

    showmessage('Hello '+name+', Welcome to our funday');
end;

edit2.Text := inttostr(adults);
edit3.Text := inttostr(children);
```

I don't know Delphi, so pardon any errors.

Comment: I think this has the identical result as the OP's code.. code is better, imo, but still the same..

Comment: Why would you think that???? It's clearly nothing like the OP's. It exits out of the loop before asking for the age instead of after.

Comment: first, your code doesn't even work.  Your variable 'name' is assumed to be the name of the form, so entering an age fails.

Comment: @JohnEasley, the `name` variable could be local as well, given the information we have. So you can't say the "code doesn't even work".

Comment: @John Your previous comment is wrong even if there would be no variable `name` and it would refer to the `Name` property of the form, it would have no effect on entering `age`. Of course it would still be a blunder, but the presented code would still work.

Comment: @TomBrunberg wouldn't entering name be setting the form name property at each iteration?

Comment: @LURD my bad, apologies

Comment: @John Yes it would, and its caption also. The name property would just work as the missing variable in this case. Does it surprise you?